# Polymer code sample snippet for observe does not change text color

Tags: javascript, polymer

Hello kind people of the Internet,

I'm attempting to use the Polymer sample snippets, but can't seem to get the following snippet example for an observe to behave properly:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element">
   <template>
     <div>{{thing.color}}</div>
     <button on-tap="{{changeColor}}">Change color</button>
     <p>{{message}}</p>
   </template>
 <script>
    Polymer({
      message: '',
      created: function() {
        this.thing = {
          color: 'red'
        };
      },
      observe: {
        'thing.color': 'colorObserver',
      },
      colorObserver: function(oldValue, newValue) {
        this.message = 'Color changed from ' + oldValue + ' to ' + newValue;
      },
      changeColor: function(e) {
        this.thing.color = this.thing.color === 'red' ? 'green' : 'red';
      }
    });
  </script>
 </polymer-element>
```

...the color of 'red' or 'green' text does not toggle, but the message text displays ok.

The link to the specific Polymer code sample snippet I'm having this minor issue with is here:
   https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-patterns/blob/master/snippets/observing-changes/watching-for-changes-to-a-nested-object.html

I'm using the sample snippet template in the Chrome Dev Editor, and again: the web page button works ok, and displays the text ok, but alas, the text color 'red' or 'green' does not show up.  I have run bower update to the components packages, and there are no errors in the JavaScript console.

Note: there is another polymer snippet template that does something very similar (toggle text color) that works just fine, link here:

https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-patterns/blob/master/snippets/basics/binding-to-a-style.html

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <p>My favorite color is <span style="color:{{color}}">{{color}}</span>.</p>
    <button on-tap="{{toggleColor}}">Toogle color</button>
  </template>
 <script>
  Polymer({
    color: 'red',
    toggleColor: function() {
      this.color = this.color === 'red' ? 'green' : 'red';
    }
  });
</script>
```

So, at this point I'm not confident I understand how the observe function works, and as a meta question:  Could anyone perhaps suggest how to go about trouble-shooting this type of issue? and-or point me towards a resource that might help with this type of trouble-shooting? (given there are no obvious errors thrown).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't "actually" bind `thing.color` to the appropriate css attribute:

```
<div style="color: {{thing.color}}">{{thing.color}}</div>
```